# Algebraic sum of any number of irreducible fractions whose denominators are all co- prime, cannot be an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let there be two numbers: $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}$, s.t. $(a,b)=(c,d)=(b,d)=1$.

The sum is assumed (for indirect, or contradiction approach) to be $k \in \mathbb {Z}$.

$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=k $$
$$\Rightarrow ad+bc=kbd$$
$$>ad=kbd-cb \Rightarrow ad=b(kd-c), \text{not possible as  } b\nmid ad$$ $$>cb=kbd-ad \Rightarrow cb=d(kb-a), \text{not possible as  } d\nmid bc$$

Hence proved.

How to extend (hopefully, the only approach would by induction) for sum of more than two fractions?

---

Also, have another question that concerns with providing a proof using better symbolic logic ( don't know how to state better), the derivation of $(a,c)=1$, by using the three equalities ($(a,b)=(c,d)=(b,d)=1$).

Any way to prove - or is there no way to prove as $(a,c)$ can go both ways; i.e. $=1, \ne 1$, as @MooS's  comment to his answer shows.

<del>My incomplete proof attempt is:</del>

<del>Also, stated using Bezout's identity:</del>

<del>$$ax + by =1 , cx + dy =1, bx + dy =1, \exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z} $$</del>
<del>(Have taken $x,y$ to mean dummy variables, and may not actually be the same for all three equalities).</del>

Comment: It might be nitpicking, but the assertion is false: $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}=2$

Comment: I hope it would work for $a,b,c,d \ne 1$.

Comment: You only need one of the fractions to be an "actual" fraction. The numerators are not relevant.

Comment: Why only one? Also, why numerators are not relevant? Do you mean that the numerators can be simply $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my proof for the case of two summands:

Actually one only needs to assume that $(b,d)=1$ and that one of the fractions is not an integer, w.l.o.g assume $\frac{a}{b} \notin \mathbb Z$.

If $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d} \in \mathbb Z$, we have $ad+bc = 0 \mod{bd}$.

Reduce this modulo $b$ to get $ad = 0 \mod b$. Since $d$ is co-prime to $b$, we obtain $a = 0 \mod b$, a contradiction to $\frac{a}{b} \notin \mathbb Z$.

---

For more summands (assuming the denominators are pairwise co-prime and one of the fractions is not an integer), the induction step is actually trivial, because if you take the sum of two fractions, the common denominator will still be co-prime to all other denominators.

Comment: Please elaborate the line : "Reduce this module ..."

Comment: Typo. Reduce this modulo.

Comment: Any help regarding the second proof for proving $(a,c) = 1$.

Comment: Why do you want to prove that? It is not needed and more importantly it just plain wrong: $\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{5}$ satisfies all your assumptions, but the numerators are not co-prime.

Comment: Thanks a ton for that. I hope a hint to prove this 'new' fact, i.e., $(a,b)=(c,d)=(b,d)=1, \text{ and } \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} \ne \text { any integer}$, then $(a,c)$ can have any value. I hope it cannot be proven, as the value of $(a,c)$ can be both ways, i.e. $=1$, or $\ne 1$. If you could give some insight into such proofs, I would be highly thankful.

Comment: So you are telling me you cannot use my example in the comment above to produce examples for any value of $(a,c)$? This should be obvious.

Comment: Does this obviousness (if you have interpreted me correctly) has any sort of proof in maths for both yes and no answers, i.e. $(a,c)$ can be any value $=1, \ne 1$?

Comment: Let $e$ be any value you wish and let $p,q$ be two primes co-prime to $d$. $e/p + e/q$ works.

Comment: But, why not just $b,d$ with $(b,d)=1$.

Comment: We have $(b,d)=1$ in my example. I do not see your problem to be honest.

Comment: If you have another question, you should take some time to carefully formulate it and ask a new question. No more comments here.

Comment: Confused, and need source to prepare next question better. So, final comment for a good source, which has details.